# Requirements for modal authentication (as a Login page iFrame or object) without getting redirected to Login page?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iframe, forms-authentication, session-timeout

There might be a few questions here, but one major question... what should be implemented if we make a modal authentication work?  Let me try to explain..

Current environment: 
ASP.NET w/ .NET 4.0 w/ forms authentication

Our customers that use our lab software have to be extra cautious of another user taking control of their computer, so we can't implement persistent timeouts (I think the last time I read, you can keep extending the timeout as long as there's something happening in ASP.NET, right?).  Even though we have password authentication throughout our laboratory rich client application, we still don't want a random person walking by some employees desk to see what they're working on and have something get compromised.  So I've been thinking about this for quite some time and tonight I had an epiphany.  What if we were to have the Login page pop up in a modal dialog within an iframe (or object tag) in a modal div that's inside of our masterpage?  How can we keep their session from ever expiring, but require them to login after the session has timed out?  Is there anything else you can think of that will be required if we were to implement something like this for it to work?  Note, we have session variables within the software that cannot be reset if this occurs.  How can we keep them persistent but still make this work?  The main thing is I want to avoid having them be redirected to the Login page.  This is rather annoying for end-users.  By law, they need to have the timeout set to 2 minutes, so I thought this would be really cool if I can make it work.  Any other things we need to watch out for??

Answer (score 1):

I can't but think that it's scary to use asp.net session, especially with forms-auth - because, the user gets 2 cookies: session and auth. Imagine what would happen if, somehow, authenticated user A would steal session cookie from authenticated user B: it would result in user A having access to all data that user B owns (unless your code checks whether user-id from auth-cookie owns the session object. In other words, I would suggest to get rid of the session, or at least add user-id value to session object and make sure you check that user id from the auth-cookie matches that within application_authorize event, maybe. You didn't ask for this info, but I think it's appropriate, regardless.

Since the session and the auth cookies have little to do with each other, as far as browser is concerned, and your goal is to keep the session alive, while auth-cookie should expire, then, you can maybe solve that by writing a piece of JS (hint: `window.setInterval`) that regularly pings some ANONYMOUS url (aspx page) at your server (make sure you add a random query to those requests; e.g. `new Date().getTime()`). The anon aspx page would need to read (do not write!) some value from the session (or simply retrieve the session object) - just to keep it alive (maybe this isn't really necessary; do experiment), but the browser WILL be sending asp.net session cookie with these requests, so you can keep the session object alive forever this way.

On the other side, your auth-cookie will expire. However you MUST set web.config settings (authentication > forms) to NOT use sliding expiration (as that mode essentially extends the validity/expiration of the auth cookie for another whatever-the-timeout-is minutes). Then, you can be sure that, after the cookie expires (e.g. after 20 min), when the user clicks on a protected link (well, a link that links to protected page; non-anon page), then they will land on login page. I know that you don't want this. So, to solve that, add another (independent) piece of javascript (hint: `window.setTimeout([code], 2 * 60 * 1000) // to fire after 2 min since the page-load`) to launch the login dialog. The login dialog would extend the auth-cookie by posting the uid/pwd and letting asp.net validate it.

Another thing: if you have ajax going on on that page, you must think of resetting these js timeouts back to 0 (or cancelling then reinitializing interval and timeout events). In other words, you can't start measuring inactivity since the page load - you have to reset the inactivity counter on every user's action (click; or at least on every ajax callback).

What I'm suggesting here may be an overkill. I would probably try to solve this differently. I would try to eliminate in-process session from the picture, and reload it based on auth-cookie's user-id from whereever user data is, every time it's needed (or once per request). I don't know why it's so important to keep the session object hanging in memory, even when the user is logged out (how do you know they won't leave for a week; keeping sessions alive would be killing your server if you had a large number of users). Maybe store the session data in database or some other caching mechanism on the network (e.g. memcached) and retrieve it once per request (e.g. in application_authorize), store it in request.context (to eliminate retrieving it multiple times from multiple places). Then, your auth-cookie will expire, and use JS to popup the login dialog a few min before the auth cookie expired (to avoid the gap where the user will land on login page if they click on a link, if you care about that even).

I hope these ideas help.